# Write And Read .txt files from FTP with C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

Is it possible to write a txt file on ftp (not upload a file to ftp!) Directly writing a txt file on ftp server) and read from a file on a ftp (not download a file from ftp!) Directly read from a txt file on ftp server? I searched but ı found upload a file and donwload a file with FtpWebRequest class. Note: FTP server uses credentials.

Comment: FTP = File Transfer Protocol :)

Comment: Sure, if you run a process locally on the FTP server, but you won't be using FTP.

Comment: I know ftp. Is there any protocol like File Data Transfer Protocol-FDTP :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The [FTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) described in [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) doesn't have any means to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I'm aware, your only option is to download or upload the file. I guess you could short-circuit it a bit by only downloading the file until you got to the part you needed, then aborting. But the whole purpose of FTP is to upload/download FILES, not content.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with help of third-party virtual file system driver which should be installed in system. There exist third-party applications which let you see the remote FTP location as a virtual disk on your computer. Once the remote FTP location is mounted this way you can use regular file I/O methods to read and write those files. You can create such application as well (not a rocket science with right tools).

Comment: This still downloads a whole file, allow you to make changes and uploads the whole file back. It is not in place changes as the OP is asking.

Comment: @Oded sorry, you are wrong. Only the part of file is being read (though certain caching and read-ahead does take place).

Comment: Can you please show me how this is achieved using the FTP protocol?

Comment: @Oded send REST X , then get Y bytes?